# Would/will be, Would/will have to be

Tags: will-would

Difference between

1.Would be.
2.Would have to be.
3.Will be.
4.Will have to be.

I need a deep explanation with examples.

Comment: Modals are *very* complicated, and there are few 'general' principles governing their use which are both reliable and useful. I think this question is too broad to be answered. If you give us a specific sentence **and context** in which those four constructions might be used we could take a stab at distinguishing them.

Comment: ... but you should do your own research first. A lot of modal usages have been covered before on ELU, and you need to show evidence that you've at least looked at some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need a deep explanation with examples.

That's a bit of a tough order but I shall try to deliver.

Overall *would* is the past tense of will. *Will* is the future tense. *Is* is the present tense and it's a little difficult to explain becuase these are verbs on the state of existing.

He **would** like that.
He **will** like that.
He **is** liking that.

They're all interesting also becuase they imply a certain amount of confidence in their usage. See for example *would* vs *may*. *May* allows us an open-endedness we don't generally have with *would*; ie the ability to be unsure about our assurance. Sometimes *would* **can** be "unsure" (example: "Would it really affect us that much?"), but that's a different kind of uncertainty. You could replace *would* with *could* and it introduces a different kind of uncertainty to the question. Could it do this? We're not sure. Would it do this? Maybe, since it doesn't seem too far out of character.

### **Would be...**

Right off the bat I can only think of the use in a question and not exactly the usage of "be" since "be" is a different tense. You'd have to use *being* becuase the usage of *being* requires you/it to already have *been*. It could have just *become* (or *became*), or whatever related applicable word you want to use. It doesn't matter, what matters is that it has *been* in some form.

> "I really don't know why I reacted like that-"
>   "*Would being* an idiot have anything to do with it?"

First off this is sarcasm, which has it's own logic and really messes with you. A legit "*would* question" is above.

Would starts the question asking about whether so-and-so is an idiot and if some apparently terrible outcome is the result of them being idiotic. They're talking about an event in the past so to reference that event they can only use past tense verb. The responder thinks so-and-so is an idiot, and this is in use an insult. The rhetorical answer to the rhetorical question of would being an idiot make someone do that is yes, yes it is. Before we compare, take a look at **would have to be**.

### **Would have to be...**

This usage still requires something to have *been*. The difference is it applies it differently. **Would be** is more cause-oriented, **would have to be** is more result-oriented. Take a look below.

> "You *would have to be* an absolute idiot to fall for that!"

**Would being cause it** vs **You'd have to be to do it.**

### **Will be...**

**Will be** is essentially the same as *will become*. Usually *will become* is clearer than *will be* becuase *be* is a weird mesh of tenses (example: "It must be." vs "Be all you can be.").

> "What *will she be* when you are done with her?"

*Be* is the verb of existence, different than *is* which is the verb of existing.

### **Will have to be...**

Again the difference between **Will have to be** and **Will be** is that **Will be** is cause-oriented while **Will have to be** is result-oriented.

> "They *will need to be*, otherwise the last of the light will go out."

Yes I replaced *have* with *need*, since they're very similar in use. However, *need* vs *have* is a different question.

**Will being do this** vs **Something will have to be to do it**.